# DDD and Unit Test, should I create entities directly or through their Domain service?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, builder, readability

Some of the entities that are under test, cannot be directly created using the constructor, but only through a Domain service, because the use of a Repository is needed, may be for some validation that requires a hit in the DB (imagine a unique code validation).

In my tests I have two options:

1. Create an entity using the domain service that exposes the entity creation, this requires me to mock all the repository interfaces needed by that service and instruct the relevant ones to behave correctly for a successfull creation
2. Somehow use directly the entity constructor (I use c# so i can expose an internal constructor to the test assembly) and get the entity bypassing the service logic.

I'm not sure on which is the best approach,
the 1st is the one I prefer because it tests the public behaviour of the Domain model, since from an outside perspective the only way to create the entity is passing through the Domanin service. But this solution brings in al lot of "Arrange" code due to the mock configuration needed.
The 2nd one is more direct, it creates the object bypassing the service logic, but it's a sort of cheating on the Domain model, it assumes that the test code knows the internals of the Domain model and that's not a good point. But the code is a bit more readable.

I make use of [Builders](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/builder-pattern-good-for-code-great-for-tests.html) the create entities in tests, so the configuration code needed by the 1st approach would be isolated in the builder code, but I still want to know what would be the correct way.

Comment: Most DB engines, either SQL or NoSQL, have their unique indexes built-in... I mean, it's being too perfectionist validating that an id or whatever is unique in your domain if you need to hit the DB for this

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that's not the point, let's assume the the validation requires a network access or something else. In addition, in case of a duplication, I want to notify the user not with an index erorr message but with a "Code "babla" already exists for a {EntityName}", so I need to check it explicitly.

Comment: You can still notify the user with a human-like message. Catch the exception that throws the whole FK/index violation!

Comment: My point is whether skipping the Domain service logic is a misuse of the domain itself

Comment: I know what's your question. That's why I used comments to criticize the thing about using domain even for unique code/id validation if you need to hit the database for this :)

Comment: Assuming I have understood the question correctly, I think if you are testing domain entities (Aggregates, value objects,..), then they are ideally not created from db, the aggregate root is responsible for that. and all the state is in memory in the domain layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are asking what 'level' you should test at. Option 2 is very much a Unit Test, as it would test the code of a single class only. Option 1 is more of an Integration Test as it would test several components together.

I tend to prefer Option 2 for unit tests, for the following reasons:

1. Unit tests are simpler and more effective if they test a single class only. If you use the factory service to create the object under test, your test doesn't have direct control over how the object is constructed. The will lead to messy and tedious test code, such as mocking all the repository interfaces.
2. I will usually have, in a different part of my test code base, actual Integration Tests (or Acceptance Tests) which test the entire application from front to back via it's public interfaces (with external dependencies such as databases mocked/stubbed out). I would expect these tests to cover Option 1 from your question so I don't really need to repeat Option 1 in the unit test suite.

You may ask, what's the point of starting up my whole application just to test a couple of classes? The answer is quite simple - by sticking to only two levels of testing, your test code base will be clean, readable and easy to refactor. If your tests are very varied in terms of the 'level' that they test at (some test a single class, some a couple of classes together, some the whole application) then the test code just becomes hard to maintain.

Some caveats:

1. This advice is for if you are developing an "application" that will be deployed and run. If you are developing a "shared library" that will be distributed to other teams to use as they see fit, then you should test from all the public entry points to the library, regardless of the 'level'. (But I still wouldn't call these tests "unit tests" and would separate them in the code base.)
2. If you don't have the ability to write full integration tests, then I would use Option 1 and 2. Just be wary of the test code base becoming bloated.

One more point - test things together if they change for the same reason. The situation you *don't* want to end up in after choosing Option 1 is having to change your Entity tests every time you make a change to the factory/repository code. If the behavior of each Entity has not changed, then you shouldn't have to change the tests.

Comment: Good answer, the maintainability (and readability) concerns are very important to me. I just can't accept the fact that tests can go beyond the line of public methods. Isn't it a violation? Or is this "violation" justyfied by the fact that tests are somhow special clients for the Domain?

Comment: The concept you are missing is that methods with the 'public' access modifier are *not* the only methods that define a public contract. The internal constructors represent a public contract with the rest of the assembly. When talking about unit tests, there is only public, or private. Anything that is not declared private is effectively public to some code somewhere. Another example is protected methods. Protected methods must be tested because they are effectively public to any subclass.

Comment: Remember also that part of the point of Unit Tests is to help encourage clean design of your code. The 'internal' access modifier is simply a tool to prevent users of the assembly from calling the method directly. It doesn't mean that there is no value to using Unit Tests to drive a clean design of your 'internal' APIs, in the same way you would use tests to drive a clean design of your 'public' API.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably avoid that conundrum by not creating your entity through a domain service in the first place.

If you feel the need to validate something about an entity before creating it, you could probably see it as a domain invariant and have it enforced by an Aggregate. That aggregate root would expose a method to create the entity.

As soon as the invariant is guaranteed by the Aggregate in charge of spawning the new Entity, everything can be tested against concrete objects in memory since the aggregate should have all needed data inside itself to check the invariant - there is no resorting to an external Repository. You can set up the creator aggregate to be in an invariant breaking state or non-invariant-breaking state all in memory and exercise the test directly on the aggregate's `CreateMyEntity` method.

[Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) by Udi Dahan is a good read on that approach - the basic idea is that entities and aggregate roots aren't just born out of nowhere.

Comment: I've not been clear enough, in my question I'm talking about aggregate root.